# How can I fix this bizarre LoadError error produced by coffeescript/asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm using the Rails 3 asset pipeline. I got into a situation where I needed to order my Javascript files in a specific way so I added them all explicitly to application.js like this:

```
//= require admin
//= require application
//= require users
...
//= require_self
...
```

It works locally but when I pushed to Heroku I got a crazy javascript (coffeescript) error:

```
Uncaught Error: LoadError: no such file to load -- ["ok", "(function() {\n\n ...
```

This continues on with the entire contents of the first coffeescript file I am including. That is to say, the error message includes a bunch of javascript code. Like it is trying to include a file whose name is a bunch of code.

How can I fix this error, or is there a better way to manually specify the order of my javascript includes?

Comment: Do you precompile assets localy or do you let Heroku do the precompilation? And, if you try to precompile your assets localy, does it go through? No errors?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with Heroku. I am seeing this same error locally.

Comment: @RyanMontgomery that's interesting. I can't make it happen locally. I recommend voting up this question if you are experiencing the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I did vote it up. I tried upgrading to rails 3.1.3 to no avail, hoping it was a strange regression in asset pipeline.

Comment: Since it happens locally for you, it should be a bit easier to debug, can you step back through your repository to see where it started happening?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.2 by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem with Heroku, it's a problem with asset compilation Rails wide

I fixed it be reverting ExecJS to version 1.3.0, seems a change in [1.3.1](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/commit/59fb97075ab4d6c02c461a147a001c50428c8fed) released last Wednesday has changed the way it's attempting to compile the Javascript

Comment: You can read about the issue here: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/82